# Error: Calling a class for no reason

Tags: php

The error is:

> Class 'Controller\Index' not found

but in all my code at any time I call this class:

**Test.php** << Script Executor

```
include_once("index.engine.php");
Index::importController();
use Controller\User;
echo User::getWorld(); // The error happens here.
```

**Index.engine.php** << Indexer Includes

```
if (!defined('HOME')) define("HOME", __DIR__."/");

class Index{

    public static function importModel(){           
        spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
            $nome = str_replace("\\", "/" , $class . '.model.php');
            if( file_exists( HOME . $nome ) ){
                include_once( HOME . $nome );
            }
        });
    }

    public static function importController(){
        spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
            $nome = str_replace("\\", "/" , $class . '.controller.php');
            if( file_exists( HOME . $nome ) ){
                include_once( HOME . $nome );
            }
        });
    }

    public static function importPersistent(){
        spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
            $nome = str_replace("\\", "/" , $class . '.persistent.php');
            if( file_exists( HOME . $nome ) ){
                include_once( HOME . $nome );
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**user.controller.php** << Only an intermediary

```
        namespace Controller{
    include_once (__DIR__ ."/../index.engine.php");
    Index::importPersistent();
    use Persistent\Test;
        class User{ 
            public static function getWorld(){
                $result = Test::getEngine(); 
                return $result;
            }
        }
    }
```

**user.persistent.php** << Function required

```
namespace Persistent{
    class Test{
        public static function getEngine(){
            $engine = "Engine is on! \o/";
            return $engine;
        }
    }
}
```

*Thanks for help me.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**user.controller.php**

```
namespace Controller{
include_once (__DIR__ ."/../index.engine.php");
Index::importPersistent();
use Persistent\Test;
    class User{ 
        public static function getWorld(){
            $result = Test::getEngine(); 
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

**I change to:**

```
namespace Controller{
use Index;
use Persistent\Test;
Index::importPersistent();
    class User{ 
        public static function getWorld(){
            $result = Test::getEngine(); 
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

The error was in the include which was called more than once, then altered to call only once in the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Controller\User; # this is used to call a namespace, in your code there is no declaration of the namespace
echo User::getWorld(); //
```

For this, one would be expected to have a file in this form

sample.php

```
namespace Controller;

class User {
   public static function getWorld() {
     ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's right, but I want to call the control and run the command ... the problem is that he is trying to import the "index", and I do not want it.

Comment: If I get you right, you want to call the getWorld() method from the controller, right?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ar5q98 -- I'm calling the method from control for the test file.

Comment: The line

    Index::importPersistent();

is trying to get "Index" again, but because of the line

    Namespace Controller;

then creates a nonexistent class.

The problem is that the Index does not stop running, and tries to include all external classes, even Index which had already been included...